# What happened to my reputation (points)?

Tags: support, reputation

I have some browser tabs that have been open for several days. 
A few of them show my reputation as either 2221 or 2231.<sup>*</sup> 
My rep is currently 2165, for a drop of 66 from the high-water mark. 
My # of posts edited and my progress toward earning a “Sportsmanship” badge
also went down.
__________
<sup>* I believe that I most recently refreshed these tabs
between 2016‑08‑18 04:00 and 2016‑08‑18 06:15;
i.e., a little under three days ago. 
Of course the reputation score in the top bar may have updated since then.</sup>

I seem to recall that,
if you (gain or) lose a lot of rep
because a user was deleted (or because of voting fraud),
you get an annotation to that effect
in the “reputation” tab of your user profile page. 
I don’t have anything like that. 
My reputation history shows a delta of +9 (one upvote and one down)
in the past four days.  This leaves an unexplained drop of 75.

From the “answers” tab I see that my answer
to [What is the next number in the series : 3, 24, 75, 175, 342, ?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/40728/19765#40817),
with a score of 1, was deleted at 04:05 (on 2016‑08‑18):

[image: deleted recent answers]

(Actually, it was the question that was deleted.) 
This explains 10 points (and the other statistics). 
If the vote breakdown on that answer
was $\Large\frac{\color{green}{+9}}{\color{red}{-8}}$,
that would explain $90-16=74$ points.  
$\Large\frac{\color{green}{+7}}{\color{red}{-6}}~\color{green}{\checkmark}$
would explain $70-12+15=73$ points,
but I really doubt that either of those happened.

This question may appear to be a duplicate of [Disappearing reputation](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1369/19765),
but the answer there was that question(s)
(where the OP got rep from answer(s)) had been deleted. 
I have investigated that avenue and pretty much ruled it out.

I presume that, if there had been a widespread glitch,
multiple people would have been affected,
and this issue would have been raised here (in meta) by now;
but I don’t see it. 
Can anybody (presumably somebody with privileges) explain
what happened to my reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also had an accepted answer on [Riddle Me: What time is it?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/riddle-me-what-time-is-it/36572#36572) which was deleted for 65 reputation points. It shows on your [Deleted Recent Answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/19765) list, but the date is the answer date, not the deletion date.

You also downvoted an answer recently for another -1, so:

```
2231 - 65 - 1 = 2165
```

Comment: Oh, the Deleted Recent Answers list shows the *post* date/time rather than the *delete* date/time!  That would explain it.  Thanks for looking into this for me, and for the explanation.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Is it just me, or is that a terribly unintuitive and uninformative display?

Comment: @PeregrineRook: It is. But it's a consequence of the [criteria for inclusion on the page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/1438). If your answer were older than 60 days, it wouldn't be shown. (It also [wouldn't have lost reputation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/se-podcast-32-jarrod-dixon-and-josh-heyer/), which isn't really a coincidence.)

Comment: Arrgghhh!  Another ***2 days*** and the rep would have "locked in" (to use [Jarrod's words](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/se-podcast-32-jarrod-dixon-and-josh-heyer)).  I lost the lottery on that one.    :-(    ⁠